# iOS detect Screenshot if App is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, screenshot

I'm new in Xcode and Objective-C, so I need your help.
I wan't to have an app which detect an Screenshot if this App is in the Background, for example you pressed the home button, so you be on the Home Screen, if you take a screenshot now I want that the app show an alert on the Home Screen.
I try this:

in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userDidTakeScreenshot:) name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)userDidTakeScreenshot:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"screenshot detected");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"screenshot detected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

But if the App enter the background and then i take a screenshot the alert don't show.
I hope you will understand my problem.

And I excuse for my english.

Comment: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification work in background mode?

Answer (score 2):

`UIAlert` will only work if you app is in the foreground, you might be able to get the user attention with an `UILocalNotification`.

Also only if your is really running in the background will you be able to detect the screenshot. So you app should be VOIP, Stream audio, accessory app, etc..

Default you app will not run in the background.

Comment: first thank you, for your answer. But the NSLog have still to work?

Comment: `NSLog` will work in the background, but only if you app is not suspended.  If you app does not falling in of the allowed background modes you app will get suspended when entering the background. The `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` might not be called when you app is in the background.

Comment: That means, that UIpplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification don't will work?

Comment: It might, not sure there is no documentation wether or not it will work, but first you should check whether you can make you app run in the background without misusing the [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23).

Comment: @rckoenes Finally, do you know if UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification work in background mode? or if it is possible detect a screenshot in background?

Answer (score 0):

"UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification" :
 I think there is no way to detect screenshot When your App in Background or suspend.
This notification only be notify when your App in foreground.